# Why we can use $\frac{1}{V}\sum_{k \in 1BZ} \approx \int_{k\in 1BZ} \frac{dk}{(2\pi)^d}$ for phonons?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, phonons

Why can we use
$$\frac{1}{V}\sum_{k \in 1BZ} \approx \int_{k\in 1BZ} \frac{dk}{(2\pi)^d}$$
where $d$ is the dimension of the lattice, for phonon related integration?

I know the above sum converted to integral is valid for free electrons in Sommerfeld model. But why can it still be used for phonons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic for phonons is exactly the same as it is for electrons. The approximation relies on the fact that the crystal is very large, so the density of allowed $\vec{k}$ in reciprocal space is very high. In that limit, the sum can be approximated as an integral. (The allowed reciprocal lattice vectors are determined by the crystal lattice; it doesn't matter if you're talking about electrons or phonons.)

For reference, see the book *Electrons and Phonons* by J. Ziman sec 1.9 (or really any good book on solid state physics).

For the record, it has nothing to do with the Bose-Einstein distribution or the actual number of phonons in the system.

Answer (score 7):

That formula comes from the following 
$$\frac{1}{V}\sum_k = \frac{1}{Na^3}\frac{(2\pi)^3}{(2\pi)^3}\sum_k = \frac{2\pi}{N_1 a}\frac{2\pi}{N_2 a}\frac{2\pi}{N_3 a}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\sum_k\\
=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\sum_k \Delta k_x \Delta k_y \Delta k_z
$$

And now the important step

> Whenever it's feasible to think that $\mathbf{N}$ **is very large**, practically $N\rightarrow\infty$ we can write 
>   $$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\sum_k \Delta k_x \Delta k_y \Delta k_z\to\int\limits_{k\in FBZ}\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}$$

which for electrons it clearly holds, but what makes you think that it will still hold for phonons?

The mean number of phonons in a given band with wavevector $k$, is given by a Bose-Einstein distribution 
$$\bar{n}_{ks} = \frac{1}{e^{\beta\hbar\omega_s(k)}-1} $$ 
where $\omega_s(k)$ is the dispersion relation of the $s$-branch. You can easily see that, at $T=0$, the mean number of phonons is finite but not at all big, while the number of electrons still remains of the order $10^{23}$. The number of electrons in a solid will always remain big, while the number of phonons will vary depending on various physical conditions.

Comment: Maybe my description is not qutie clear. It's the integration related with phonon wave vector k,not with phonons.

Comment: Isn't the number of phonons equal to 0 at T=0?